# Mysql install and remove issues

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I installed mysql on ubuntu server and i dont know what went wrong...it didnt install a mysql root user so i tried to uninstall and start over and now i cant unistall

i tried this

```
apt-get remove php5-mysql
apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get autoremove
```

but when i do

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

> ```
> root      6066  0.0  0.0   1772   540 pts/1    S    03:21   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
> mysql     7065  0.0  0.6  58936 11900 pts/1    Sl   03:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --   basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid -- socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
> root      7066  0.0  0.0   2956   688 pts/1    S    03:33   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
> root     22804  0.0  0.0   3056   780 pts/1    R+   04:14   0:00 grep mysql
> ```

so i killed the processes and then tried to reinstall like this

```
apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password 'root'
```

but i get this

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

im confused..i keep installing and uninstalling mysql and the same result..any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root mysql
mysql>UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('PASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
sudo killall mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: i get a fail on sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Comment: Try 'sudo killall mysqld'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1` (not sure about exact version of the package, I don't have an Ubuntu box here right now, it depends on Ubuntu version anyway, so you'd better check it using `dpkg -l | grep mysql-server`).
`dpkg-reconfigure` resets a root password on Debian, I assume its behaviour is the same on Ubuntu.